# ¿Cómo convertir un string a un double con todos los decimales que tenga el string?

Tags: java, android, string, double

Estoy realizando una app, que guarda las coordenadas de un lugar, la API de Google me devuelve un valor muy grande ej: -64.22333584822 al usar Double.parseDouble(); redonodea el valor haciendo que pierda precision en las coordenadas. Quisiera saber como convertirlo a double con todos los numeros que me muestra de latitud y longitud.

Comment: qué tratamiento recibirá el número después? dicho de otra manera es necesario pasarlo a double? si es para guardar y recuperar con un string bastaría, si es para cálculos de distancias 5 digitos=1m, 6 digitos= 10cm aproximadamente

Comment: mmm esta hablando de coordenadas tendría que ir a un mapa esa variable

Comment: si por eso pregunto, si la precisión es importante y para qué se usará el número.

Comment: Esperemos su pronta respuesta

Comment: El numero lo usare para guardarlo en la base de datos, y posterior mente en el mapa mostrar todas las localizaciones almacenadas en la base de datos. Pero el incoveniente es que tiene que tener todos los decimales para mayor precisión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede<sup>1</sup>.

Hay dos factores:

- La precisión de *double* es finita.
- Los números decimales no siempre tienen una representación exacta en binario, por ejemplo `0.1` pasa a ser `0.0001100[1100]` (el `1100` se repite de forma periódica)<sup>2</sup>

Dos soluciones:

- Usar `java.math.BigDecimal` que permite representar números decimales con una precisión arbitraria.
- Preguntarse si la precisión es necesaria.

  Tu información indica una posición, es decir es latitud o longitud.
  Con un radio aprox. de 40.000 km, un grado es como máximo unos 111
  km.

  Eso significa que si tienes un problema de redondeo en el quinto
  decimal, el error máximo será de alrededor de un metro. El error
  introducido por el redondeo será probablemente mucho menor que el
  error introducido al obtener la información del GPS o en los datos de
  Google.

  Si tienes un error con el noveno o el décimo decimal, el error será tan pequeño que no podrías ver la diferencia sin microscopio<sup>3</sup>...

---

<sup>1</sup>Al menos, no para todos los números.

<sup>2</sup>Notar que aquí no estoy usando el estándar IEEE para representar al número, solo la conversión directa decimal a binario. Pero sirve de ejemplo.

<sup>3</sup>A veces no hay más remedio que aceptar que el mundo es análogico.

Comment: la segunda parte de la respuesta podría ampliarse con la info de este hilo: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674

Comment: Excelente tu respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score -2):

Prueba con esto :

```
String[] latLng = "-34.8799074,174.7565664".split(",");
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng[0]);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng[1]);
```

Debería funcionar correctamente :D

Comment: Esto no es lo que se pide...

Comment: El que pregunta ya sabe como hacer esto, lo que pregunta es cómo eliminar la pérdida de precisión en el `parseDouble`. Incluso menciona el `parseDouble` en la pregunta.

Comment: Con la respuesta que he dado no pierde la precisión :) es más puedes probar y puedes dar otro -1 a tu respuesta :D

Comment: Creo que será mejor que repases como funcionan los números en binario http://gcp.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/_media/integrantes:psantamaria:fortran:f77notes:f77-dec2bin.pdf y luego el IEEE 754 https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante antes de responder...

Comment: Has probado? bueno a las finales le ayudará a la persona que solicitó esta respuesta (: